# how to solve the complex Integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

how to solve the integral

$$\int_{-\lambda_1\cdot x_1}^{-\lambda_1^2}\frac{e^z(1-e^z)^{n-1})}z dz$$

I have to find entropy of paramter of the exponential distribution under different loss functions. For that I need the value of the above integral. I tried it by using "integration by-parts" method but didnt get the result as it expands.So please help me to get the reliable result.